# Trying to Unlink Image from Folder using Localhost, php and mysqli

Tags: php, image, mysqli, localhost, unlink

I have a database on localhost phpmyadmin, when i upload an image to the database it works fine (it inserts into the db and stores in the folder); However, when i try to delete the image, the record from the database gets deleted but the image does not delete from the folder. 
Am i placing the unlink in the wrong place?

Code to store to folder:

```
$alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";
$pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
$alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) 
{
    $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
    $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
}
$random = implode($pass);

$imageName = $random.$_FILES['file']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'../angelimg/'.$imageName);
```

Code when clicking delete button:

```
if(isset($_POST['imgDelete']))
{

    $imgID = trim($_POST['imgID']);

    include("../../services/databaseConnection.php");

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "DELETE FROM ServiceImage WHERE imgID = ?"))
    {

        //bind
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $imgID);
        //unlink image from folder
        unlink('../angelimg/'.$imageName);
        //execute
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
        //close
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    //close db
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    //direct user to confirmation page of successful image upload 
    //echo("check directory");
    Header("Location: Confirmation.php");
}
```

Comment: `$imageName` is undefined in your code while deleting!!

Comment: the `$imageName` is defined within the same php tag, would it still not be recognized ?

Comment: echo `$imageName` and check what it return??

Comment: check your unlink() path that is correct?

Comment: the unlink path is correct, since the image is storing to that folder @MayankVadiya

Comment: i think @Saty is right @Christina Chotilal i also not recognized `$imageName`

Comment: can you echo $imageName in your script

Comment: Please read about scope and variable life. `$imageName` is not necessarily in the scope...

Comment: ok the `echo($imageName);` shows as an undefined index, do i need to define it within the `if(isset($_POST['imgDelete']))` ? @Saty

Comment: Before delete query you need a select query to fetch file name from database!!

Comment: @Saty Thank You!, it works !!